# Reshape tibble, change columns to rows?

Tags: r

How do I reshape a 2x4 tibble into a 2x2 tibble? Example:

```
 a b c d
 x x x x
```

into

```
  c d
a x x
b x x
```

Comment: Your output looks like it has row names, tibble strongly discourages them. It would be easier if "a" and "b" would be in a (real) column, is which case have you tried `tidyr::pivot_longer`?

Comment: Sorry it doesn't have to be a tibble.  It could be a dataframe or a table, doesn't matter.  I just want the values stacked on top of each other, instead of all spread out horizontally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `base R`, we can construct the `matrix` from `unlist`ing the tibble

```
dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(tbl1), 2, 2,
   dimnames = list(names(tbl1)[1:2], names(tbl1)[3:4])))
```

-output

```
> dat
  c d
a x x
b x x
```

#### data

```
tbl1 <- structure(list(a = "x", b = "x", c = "x", d = "x"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```